# docker-compose and override variables

Tags: docker

Is there a way to override this variable with docker compose?
I want assign the json string to an environment variable.

```
{
  "HealthChecksUI": {
    "HealthChecks": [
      {
        "Name": "HTTP-Api-Basic",
        "Uri": "http://localhost:6457/healthz"
      }
    ]    
  }
}
```

Doesn't work like this

```
environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=api.local
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
      - 'HealthChecksUI__HealthChecks__Uri=https://api.local/'
```

Problem is array I assume

Comment: you meant assign the json string to an environment variable?

Comment: yes true. I want assign the json string to an environment variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  busybox:
    image: busybox
    command: ["ash","-c","sleep 3600"]
    environment:
      JSON: |-
        {
          "HealthChecksUI": {
            "HealthChecks": [
              {
                "Name": "HTTP-Api-Basic",
                "Uri": "http://localhost:6457/healthz"
              }
            ]    
          }
        }
```

docker exec into the container and echo $JSON will show you the json string.

Comment: Thank you. What about like this?

- 'HealthChecksUI__HealthChecks__Uri=https://api.local/'

I have many env

Comment: What do you mean... can you post a new question.